# JavaFX texturing an imported 3D object

Tags: 3d, textures, javafx-8, collada

So I'm trying to import a collada .dae file into a Javafx scene using ColModelImporterJFX by InteractiveMesh.

I've got the model import from jar working and rendering into the scene, but there isn't any usefull documentation regarding adding PhongMaterials to the returned MeshViews.

```
ColModelImporter station = new ColModelImporter();
station.setResourceBaseUrl(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("models/Station"));
station.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("models/station.dae"));
```

The only node in the returned node array appears to be a Group containing all nodes.

```
Group model = (Group)(station.getImport()[0]);
root.getChildren().addAll(model);
```

What I do know is that the method getNamedMaterials() returns a map of materials with no clue on how to actually apply them.

```
Map<String, PhongMaterial> tex = station.getNamedMaterials();
```

Although I did find out a way to apply a material to each MeshView seperatly (the group model contains another group that contains all MeshView nodes), it doesn't help me at all since I have no way of knowing which material goes with which MeshView.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ((Group) model.getChildren().get(0)).getChildren().size(); i++) {
        ((MeshView) ((Group) model.getChildren().get(0)).getChildren().get(i)).setMaterial(somematerial);
}
```

I did try out my 3D model with ModelBrowserJFX and it works as it should.

[image: representation]

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried without applying the material? The different meshviews should have already their material applied. That's why you see them fine using the model browser.

Comment: Yeah it's all white :/

Comment: Maybe that's because the light. Do you have some lights applied? I've just tried the collada sample at InteractiveMesh, I don't have to add materials.

Comment: This does get me thinking that perhaps the textures werent located correctly... I doubt that getResourceBaseUrl does much.

Comment: Yes I have lights and also a lot of objects that have textures (primitives) on the scene so that definitely works

Comment: Sometimes certain lights can overexpose the model, so may looks white. Try to import just this model without lights.

Comment: Turns out it wasnt the lighting but I messed up the texture path by doing the station.setResourceBaseUrl, deleted that and now it works just fine. I guess I was overthinking things a bit :P Thanks for the help :D
http://i.imgur.com/94Dfnil.png

Answer (score 0):

PhongMaterials are already applied, but their URLs are not right (at least that was my case). If you use **windows** and **TIFF** file it may happen that such a texture you won't be able to upload by **JavaFX Image**.

This code will you show where the problem is.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/models/hst.3ds");
ModelImporter modelImporter = new TdsModelImporter();
modelImporter.read(url);
Node[] nodes = (Node[]) modelImporter.getImport();
Map<String, PhongMaterial> mapTexs = modelImporter.getNamedMaterials();
Iterator<String> it = mapTexs.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    PhongMaterial material = mapTexs.get(it.next());
    if(Objects.nonNull(material.getBumpMap())) {
       printErrors(material.getBumpMap());
    }
    if(Objects.nonNull(material.getDiffuseMap())) {
       printErrors(material.getDiffuseMap());
    }
    if(Objects.nonNull(material.getSpecularMap())) {
       printErrors(material.getSpecularMap());
    }
}

private void printErrors(Image image) {
    System.out.println(image.getException().getMessage());
}
```

**METHOD 1**

You will need to change the image with the correct URL, which then you set the individual **PhongMaterial**. As you can see I created folder in **src** named textures and there I added all textures. This method have one big disadvatage. The value of variable *key* have to be same as name of your texture file.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/models/hst.3ds");
ModelImporter modelImporter = new TdsModelImporter();
modelImporter.read(url);
Node[] nodes = (Node[]) modelImporter.getImport();
Map<String, PhongMaterial> mapTexs = modelImporter.getNamedMaterials();
Iterator<String> it = mapTexs.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
      String key = it.next();
      mapTexs.get(key).setDiffuseMap(new Image("/textures/" + key + ".bmp"));
}
```

**METHOD 2**

You add your textures there, where model is located in your project. So, in my case they have same location as my model and that means I will put them into folder [models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAiyR.png). This method is much easier than the previous one.

Used model is not in my owning. It is made by DigitalSpace Corporation.